# Keeping text on database VS .txt files? (read only, no search queries)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, filesystems

There are 10 millions comments on a MySQL table. Average length of comments is 250 characters.

I only use this type of query when I'm working with `comment` field:

```
SELECT comment,other_fields from table where article_id=123;
```

*(It returns a collection of comments for an article)*

No searches in comment or updates.

---

**Should I choose to store collection of comments for each article in a .txt file?**

There are average of 200 comments for each article.

An average of 50000 character for each .txt file.

500,000 .txt files.

**My objective is to make "hard disk usage as little as possible" without causing too much performance tradeoff.**

Comment: 10 megs in a database is nothing. I'd leave it, if not because you don't need to be bothered to put yourself through the work of moving it.

Comment: @JamesMcDonnell *millions

Comment: 10 million rows in a database is nothing. 100 million rows would still be nothing.

Comment: I would still leave the information in the database. If you're truly worried about hd usage, you could try compressing the table http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression-usage.html?

Comment: @JamesMcDonnell Thanks, it only compresses about 30% which is too low for my needs.

Comment: For what reason do you need more storage space? How much space does your database server have?

Comment: @JamesMcDonnell it is a side project and i don't want to worry about it later when it hit the limit. i'm in the process of testing so i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference of just reading data from file or from database is insignificant. If you want to just write data into one file and just read all of them later, then it would be pointless to use database for it. However once you may want to have numbers of such files or even search within them for some key (article_id), always use database. Since once you create an index (preferably primary) on article_id, it would find and fetch the data with such efficiency you would hardly beat with any algorithm written by yourself.